# Dealing with large number of small json files using pyspark

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have around `376K` of `JSON` files under a directory in `S3`. These files are `2.5 KB` each and contain only a single record/file.  When I tried to load the entire directory via the below code via `Glue ETL` with `20 workers`:

```
spark.read.json("path")
```

It just didn't run. There was a `Timeout` after 5 hrs. So, I developed and ran a `shell script` to merge the records of these files under a single file, and when I tried to load it, it just displays a single record. The merged file size is `980 MB`. It worked fine for 4 records when tested locally after merging those 4 records under a single file. It displayed 4 records as expected.

I used the below command to append the JSON records from different files under a single file:

```
for f in Agent/*.txt; do cat ${f} >> merged.json;done;
```

It doesn't have any nested JSON. I even tried the `multiline` option but didn't work. So, what could be done in this case? As per me, when merged it is not treating records separately hence causing the issue. I even tried `head -n 10` to display the `top 10 lines` but it goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information, especially about your Spark UI, where does it stuck, which one causing 5 hours reading etc

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that access. However, for now, I solved it using a shell script.

Comment: DO you have a new line between each record? Can you provide a sample of your files before merging and after merging?

Comment: I was actually trying to insert a new line via the code mentioned in the post but wasn't able to do so. So after a lot of exploring I came across `jq` for processing JSON. Post merging the records were like dictionaries separated by `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my shell script that was being used to merge multiple small files. Post merge, records weren't aligned properly due to which they weren't treated as separate records.

Since I was dealing with a `JSON` dataset, I used the `jq` utility to process it. Below is the shell script that would merge a large number of records in a `faster way` into one file:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' + | jq -s '.' > output.txt
```

Later on, I was able to load the `JSON` records as expected with the below code:

```
spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("path")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into trouble in the past working with thousands of small files. In my case they where csv files not json. One of hte thing I did to try and debug was to create a for loop and load smaller batches then combine all the data frame together. During each iteration I would call an action to force the execution. I would log the progress to get an idea of it was making progress . And monitor how it was slowing down as the job progressed

Comment: I think there is a problem when I am merging the records...It is not treating it as a separate record...